# Reading multiple files with csv.DictReader and os.listdir()

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple files in one directory and I want to open and read the ones that end with `'.csv'` using `csv.DictReader`. I know how to use `csv.Dictreader` if you have to open one file:

```
file = open("name_file")
reader = csv.DictReader(file)
for row in reader:
```

I know that `os.listdir()` return a list with all the files in working directory, maybe I can help myself out with `os.listdir`?

Comment: Take this however you like, but you should probably familiarize yourself with basic Python / programming before trying to read many CSVs in a directory. If you're capable of understanding the code you've shared above, then you should be able to know the answer, but the fact that you're asking this questions means you don't understand that code well enough. Programming beyond your current skill level is `dangerous`, even for such seemingly trivial tasks. **Please look into basic programming tutorials first**.

Comment: I would suggest using the [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob()) function instead of `os.listdir()` because it accepts wildcard filepath names. For example `csvfiles = glob.glob('/path/to/a/folder/*.csv')`.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, albeit `glob.glob()` would probably be better due to wildcard path names.
Even so, one could go about it in such a manner:

```
for a_file in os.listdir("your_dir"):
    if a_file.endswith(".csv"):
        reader = csv.DictReader(open("your_dir/" + a_file))
```